# Delete not working

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

Why can't I remove record from mysql database using `.Delete()`?

Here is an example:

```
tx := db.Begin()
if err := tx.Delete(&User{}, id).Error; err != nil {
  fmt.Print(err)
  tx.Rollback()
} else {
  fmt.Print("Rows affected: %d", tx.RowsAffected) // Always returns 0
  tx.Commit()
}
```

Using `tx.First(&user, id)` works and return user correctly

I tried:
`tx.Unscoped().Delete(...)` also not working
`tx.Exec("delete from users where (id = ?)", id)` RowsAffected = 0
`tx.First(&user, id); tx.Delete(&user)` not working

p.s. User with id `id` exists in database

Comment: what if you commit before print affected rows?

Comment: @koshvery in fact i wrote this code on this site. In my project commit is before print. I tried change and nothing changed

Comment: Try `Delete(&User{Id=id})`.

Comment: @leafbebop. It has syntax error because id field is from gorm.Model inner struct and `=` should be `:`. I tried `tx.Delete(&User{Model: gorm.Model{ID: id}})` and the same error

Comment: Oh it is a typo and I am on mobile. What is your user schema exactly?

Comment: @leafbebop i think this question will be freezed until someone ask the same because i decided to use raw sql in my project

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to use `db.Unscoped().delete()`

Answer (score 2):

When I upgrade to v1.9.x, `DELETE()` is not working. And I rollback to v1.0, it worked correctly.

After turning on DB Log, I found it's gorm v1.9 new feature: **Auto Create/Update**

Reference is here: http://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Auto-Create-Update

So if you update field after deleting something, it will insert data back into database.

try skip Auto Create/Update like this.

```
db.Set("gorm:association_autoupdate", false).Set("gorm:association_autocreate", false).Create(&user)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! In my case clearing the association after deleting the rows worked:
`db.Model(&user).Association("Languages").Clear()`

Answer (score 0):

// First Find record and that struct to use for delete user:

```
 tx := db.Begin()

  // Read
  var user User
  tx.First(&user, id) // find product with id 1

  // Delete - delete user
  //tx.Delete(&user)

if err := tx.Delete(&user).Error; err != nil {
  fmt.Print(err)
  tx.Rollback()
} else {
  fmt.Print("Rows affected: %d", tx.RowsAffected) // Always returns 0
  tx.Commit()
}
```

Comment: this approach is in my fail tries block (Not working)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
tx := db.Begin()
delTx := tx.Delete(&User{}, id)
if err := delTx.Error; err != nil {
  fmt.Print(err)
  tx.Rollback()
} else {
  fmt.Print("Rows affected: %d", delTx.RowsAffected)
  tx.Commit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to delete the user through

```
var u User
db.Unscoped().Delete(&u, "id = ? ", id)
```